# Identifying all the quasigroups of order $3$ up to isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, quasigroups

According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup#Number_of_small_quasigroups_and_loops), there are $5$ non-isomorphic quasigroups of order $3$. I have been able to find $4$ of them:

- the cyclic group of order $3$
- a commutative quasigroup with $3$ idempotent elements
- a commutative quasigroup with no idempotents
- a noncommutative quasigroup with $1$ idempotent (i.e. subtraction $\bmod 3$)

Can someone help me find the fifth one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All $5$ different quasigroups are listed with multiplication tables in figure $1$ on page $4$ in the article [Classification results in quasigroup and loop theory](http://ccg.doc.gold.ac.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/sorge_carolinae08.pdf) by Sorge, Colton, Mccasland and Meier.

Answer (score 3):

The remaining quasigroup structure is hard to see because it is nearly identical to one you've already identified: For any quasigroup $(S, \,\cdot\,)$, we can canonically define another quasigroup $(S, \odot)$ by
$$s \odot t := t \cdot s .$$
The first three quasigroup operations $(S, \,\cdot\,)$ in the question statement are commutative and so in each case $(S, \odot) = (S, \,\cdot\,)$. But for the fourth operation, $(\Bbb Z / 3 \Bbb Z, -)$, our construction gives the quasigroup operation $$a \ominus b := b - a ,$$ and the quasigroups $(\Bbb Z / \Bbb 3 Z, -)$ and $(\Bbb Z / \Bbb 3 Z, \ominus)$ are not isomorphic (the former has a right identity but the latter does not).

**Remark** If a bijection $\phi: (S, \,\cdot\,) \to (T, \star)$ of quasigroups satisfies
$$\phi(a - b) = \phi(b) \ominus \phi(a)$$
for all $s, s' \in S$, we call $\phi$ a *(quasigroup) anti-isomorphism*. By construction, for any quasigroup $(S, \,\cdot\,)$, the identity map $S \to S$ is an anti-isomorphism $(S, \,\cdot\,) \to (S, \odot)$.

Up there are five quasigroups of order $3$ up to isomorphism, but only four quasigroups of order $3$ up to isomorphism and anti-isomorphism.

See [this answer to a closely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1217257/155629) for more.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to a recent version of Maple, you can generate these (or for other, small orders) using the built-in Magma package:

```
> with( Magma ):
> L := Enumerate( 3, quasigroup, output = list );
                [1    2    3]  [1    2    3]  [1    3    2]  [1    3    2]  [2    1    3]
                [           ]  [           ]  [           ]  [           ]  [           ]
          L := [[2    3    1], [3    1    2], [2    1    3], [3    2    1], [1    3    2]]
                [           ]  [           ]  [           ]  [           ]  [           ]
                [3    1    2]  [2    3    1]  [3    2    1]  [2    1    3]  [3    2    1]

> map( IsGroup, L );
                       [true, false, false, false, false]

> map( IsCommutative, L );
                        [true, false, false, true, true]

> map( CountIdempotents, L );
                              [1, 1, 1, 3, 0]
```

The output produces the quasigroups as matrices representing their multiplication tables, with the underlying set taken to be $\{1, 2,\ldots, n\}$; here, with $n=3$.  I've assigned the list of Cayley tables to the name L in order to use it in the subsequent property explorations.