# Does this composition table necessarily define a group?

Tags: group-theory

We know that each row (and each column) of composition table of a finite group, is a rearrangement (permutation) of the elements of the group.

How about the other way round? If we have a composition table where each row and each column is a permutation of the elements of a set, does this composition table necessarily define a group?

If not then give a counter example.

Comment: You need to check associativity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Consider

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\ast & e & a & b\\
\hline
e & e & a & b\\
a & b & e & a\\
b & a & b & e
\end{array}.$$

There is no identity, so it cannot be a group.

Comment: $+1$ “Not only example is the best way to teach, it is the only way.” I firmly support this concept:  Albert Schweitzer

Answer (score 6):

What you describe is a [quasigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup).

A quasigroup is an ordered pair $(A,\cdot)$, where $A$ is a set, and $\cdot$ is a binary operation on $A$ with the property that for all $a,b\in A$ there exist unique solutions to the equations $a\cdot x = b$ and $y\cdot a=b$. If you think in terms of the [Cayley table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_table), you ask that each row and each column contain each element of $A$ exactly once; that is, that the Cayley table be a [Latin square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square).

[Quasigroups that are not groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/755410/742) exist for all orders greater than or equal to $3$; if you allow the empty set, it is also a quasigroup that is not a group.

A quasigroup is a group if and only if the operation is associative.

Answer (score 1):

For an example with an identity element and inverses, consider
$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\ast & e & a & b & c & d\\
\hline
e & e & a & b & c & d \\
a & a & e & c & d & b \\
b & b & d & e & a & c \\
c & c & b & d & e & a \\
d & d & c & a & b & e
\end{array}.$$
It is easy to find triples that do not associate, but the nonassociativity can also be seen from the fact that this loop (quasigroup with identity element) has order 5 but every element has order 2, hence Lagrange's theorem does not hold.